# ArcGIS Foreground progress bar sitting at 99%

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

Running the Interpolate Polygon to Multipatch tool and watched it work from 1% through 99% in 1% increments. Got to 99% and has been sitting there for a while.

Is it still working or did something break? Is this normal?

Comment: Try checking the **Task Manager** and see if your program is using CPU usage. If it is then it's likely that it is still processing the data and you just have to wait a while.

Comment: @Joseph Program state has changed to "Not Responding" when clicked on it, so I cant view its CPU usage %.

Comment: It could still be working even when showing Not Responding, depending on the size of the input. At least ive seen it happen doing large Dice or Buffer executions.